# Different purchases in Apple receipt

Tags: ios, receipt-validation

I.m testing my app with in-app purchases. For testing i'm using two devices, each logged with the same iTunes account, i've purchased (in sandbox) some products, but when i retrive the receipt and verify it with Apple server, i've noticed that the purchases are not the same, but the account is the same.
Is this the normal behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In-App-Purchases are bound to an user account, not a device.
You can't buy non-consumable products more than one time anyway.

> > Non-consumable products are purchased only once by a particular user. Once a non-consumable product is purchased, it is provided to all devices associated with that user’s iTunes account. Store Kit provides built-in support to restore non-consumable products on multiple devices.

Apple require that purchases be restorable on every device that is associated with a common account and that the user be allowed to reinstall the software and restore the purchase on the same device as many times as they like.

In 99.99% of cases, iTunes accounts are linked to credit card details. People therefore tend not to share them. In theory you could use the same login on more than one devices but you'd run the risk of whatever anti-fraud measures Apple have in place flagging up a potential card theft.